# Process Builder Flow Error in Case and Account Objects

Tags: chatter, process-builder

I have a process builder running to capture requirements from **Account** and **Case** Object in Salesforce. I created a new custom Field called New_Field_Internal_Account (simple checkbox). There are more fields and dependencies related to that Process Builder.

My Process Builder variables are For example: from Case Object I have Assert.Product2.Support_Team__c, Priority, Account.New_Field_Internal_Account, and Status.
I am at Prelim Environment and I need to populate a series of messages to Chatter.

> Use Case: When a client change a Subject, Description, Status,
>   Priority and is a New_Field_Internal_Account then the Process Builder
>   will populate and display with the Data Flow to the Chatter.

All things are good until An error occurred at element myDecision (FlowDecision).

> The flow failed to access the value for
>   myVariable_current.Asset.Product2.Support_Team__c because it hasn't
>   been set or assigned.

Anyone knows how to fix or handle this issue. I was researching and definitely try to complete and compare few Validation Rules, workflows, permission sets but it is impossible to deal with Process Builder and other kind of permission issues. We cannot debug, test coverage, any development task to test the accurate of the Process Builder ("BETA" version).

Thanks.

Below attached is the issue:

[image]

Comment: when you added this new custom field, did you add it to your flow variable too? As in, you need to make sure you fetch this new field, and then use it for assignment. I haven't quite understood your issue, but something to look into!